# How to create user defined exception in a procedure?

Tags: oracle, exception, plsql

Using a procedure adds an employee record into the employee table, also validates the input values salary must be always greater than or equal to 500, raise a user-defined exception for any validation error.

Comment: This isn't a title

Comment: You're running into an issue? What issue? What have you tried? You need to edit your question to demonstrate the specific problem you have and then we can begin to help you. We will not do your homework for you, though!

Answer (score 0):

You can create something like this. Add parameters for other columns as well

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insert_emp (salary NUMBER)
AS

  invalid_salary EXCEPTION;

BEGIN

  IF salary < 500 THEN 
    RAISE invalid_salary;
  ELSE 
    
    INSERT INTO employees(salary) VALUES (salary);
    COMMIT;
  END IF;

END;
```

You can also associate an Exception number with the exception

Exception number for user-defined exceptions must be in the range of -20000 to -20999

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insert_emp (salary NUMBER)
AS

  invalid_salary EXCEPTION;
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT (invalid_salary, -20100);

BEGIN

  IF salary < 500 THEN
    RAISE invalid_salary;
  ELSE

    INSERT INTO employees(salary) VALUES (salary);
    COMMIT;
  END IF;

END;
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a homework problem so I'll let using a trigger go, except a possible gotta and th show a better way of handling it. You raise the user defined exception "invalid salary" however unless your code handles it Oracle will throw the error "ORA-06510 Unhandled user defined exception", indicating it does not know what with it. So what is a better way: Define the column and include a check constraint on it.

```
Create table employees (...
                       , salary number(8,2) not null 
                         constraint salary_less_then_minimum check (salary >= 500)
                       , ...);
```

Comment: It is mentioned in the question that it should be a procedure.